# How handle different JSON schema for an entity list

Tags: php, json, api, rest

I want to develop a service to get a list of some special products from different store APIs, then sort them based on the best price. The output JSON of each API is different from another one. For example:

API No. 1 returns:

```
{
   products:
      {
         p1:
           {
              name: product1,
              price: 10
           }
         p2:
           {
              name: product2,
              price: 20
           }
      }
}
```

API No. 2 returns:

```
{
   products:
      {
         p1:
           {
              p_name: product1,
              tax: 2
              price: 9
              total_price: 11
           }
         p3:
           {
              p_name: product3,
              tax: 3
              price: 15
              total_price: 18
           }
      }
}
```

My question is, I should develop a helper class for each of these APIs to handle them separately? What happens if we want to add more resources by adding more APIs? How can I have a service to handle any kind of product API?

Second question: what is the best solution to prevent calling all APIs in each user request for getting products? Should I save them in a database for a specific time?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should normalize the output of the APIs.
Define one common format and convert the results you get to this common format.
You probably want to tag each record to know its origin.

As for your second question: that depends mostly on how long the obtained data is valid.
If the prices can change any moment you may not want to cache.